# Handle backgroundSession with NSURLSession in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, download, background-service

backgroundSession is not working well with my app the download sometime stop and sometime done but the file saving fails

here is the code i am using just converted it today into swift but i am not sure if it's right

*** AppDelegate ***

```
var backgroundSessionCompletionHandler: ()! = Void()

    func application(application: UIApplication, handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession identifier: String, completionHandler: () -> Void) {
        self.backgroundSessionCompletionHandler = completionHandler()
    }
```

*** DownloadViewController ***

```
func URLSessionDidFinishEventsForBackgroundURLSession(session: NSURLSession) {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
        if (appDelegate.backgroundSessionCompletionHandler != nil) {
            var completionHandler:Void = appDelegate.backgroundSessionCompletionHandler
            appDelegate.backgroundSessionCompletionHandler = nil
        }
        NSLog("All backgroundSession Done")
    }
```

is there anything wrong with the code or is there any other useful way to do this

Comment: Hi @Amro have you found a solution in the end? :-)

Comment: my problem was in the (didCompleteWithError) but i solved it if you need to know how to handle it?
here is how : 

`func backgroundSession() -> NSURLSession{
        var session:NSURLSession! = nil
        var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0
        dispatch_once(&onceToken) {
            var sessionConfiguration:NSURLSessionConfiguration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier("https://www.Exmaple.com")
            session = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
        }
        return session
    }`